# comparing timestamp of the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe similar to the one below. I have to compare the timestamp of rows. if the timestamp of the rows is within 1 hour then get the name from the row which has a value and populate it in other rows which don't have.

**current data**

```
      timestamp           name      Maths   Science   History
0   2021-08-09 10:18:48   Anni
1   2021-08-09 10:18:51             89                  34
2   2021-08-09 10:19:26                        76
3   2021-08-11 12:39:24             43
4   2021-08-11 12:39:45   Jeff                           65
5   2021-08-11 12:45:05   Jerry                65
```

**expected data**

```
       timestamp          name      Maths   Science   History
0   2021-08-09 10:18:48   Anni
1   2021-08-09 10:18:51   Anni       89                  34
2   2021-08-09 10:19:26   Anni                76
3   2021-08-11 12:39:24   Jeff       43
4   2021-08-11 12:39:45   Jeff                           65
5   2021-08-11 12:45:05   Jerry                65
```

But I can not find logic to this problem. Any idea?

Comment: What should the output be if the 4th row is  `3   2021-08-09 10:39:24   Jeff      43              `

Comment: @Thekingis007 there are no duplicates in the data

Comment: it is not a duplicate the timestamp of the row is within 1 hour but the column name has the value of Jeff

Comment: @Thekingis007 now I understand. Then leave the row as it is because it has the column name value

Comment: What about using pandas ffill() function ?

Comment: kindly provide the source dataframe as a dictionary: ``df.to_dict()`` ; it is much easier to reproduce this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
n=0
first = df.timestamp[0]
empty_list = []
for time in df.timestamp:
    diff = time - first
    if diff > pd.Timedelta("1h"):
        n+=1
        first = time
    empty_list.append(n)

df["helper"] = empty_list

df["name"] = df.groupby("helper")["name"].ffill().bfill()

del df["helper"]
```

Comment: I thought It needed an iterative solution.